# career profile won't retain ordering of jobs

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

I added a new job, but i cannot get it to move to the top of the list of positions.  dates are correct, and I move it up using arrows, but visiting my profile shows it back down at the bottom.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I am trying to reproduce this, but am unsuccessful. Walk me through the steps you are taking?

Comment: Pics or it didnt happen

Answer (score 1):

Tagging this norepro until we get more details.